# Response - 200 But the message is not getting posted to Telegram Group

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Based on educational website, I tried to create a simple telegram bot to post messages in Telegram group.

- I created bot using bot father and created a telegram group.
- I added the bot in the telegram group.
- I have disabled the "Privacy mode" & allow groups inside BotFather bot settings.

This is my code:

```
import requests
bot_id = '261600102:AAGx**************uRljA'
chat_id = '27*****'
#chat_id = "MyPythonTesting"
message = input('ENTER THE MESSAGE:     ')
url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_id}/sendmessage?chat_id={chat_id}&test={message}"
url = f"https://core.telegram.org/bot{bot_id}/sendmessage?chat_id={chat_id}&test={message}"
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
```

I tried above code and getting the response as 200. My message is not getting posted in the telegram group.

I used both different urls.

For the first url,

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_id}/sendmessage?chat_id={chat_id}&test={message}
```

I get this error:

```
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with 
url: /bot261600102:AAG********7uRljA/sendmessage?chat_id=276******&test=esae (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001AC0425F910>: Failed to resolve 'api.telegram.org' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)"))
```

For the second url, I am getting a http 200 as response, but the message is not getting posted.

Awaiting your reply

### Thank you

i modified the code as below

```
import requests
bot_id = '261600102:AAGx**********YHCCeXV6VqD67uRljA'
chat_id = "MyPythonTesting"
message = input('ENTER THE MESSAGE:     ')
url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_id}/sendmessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={message}"
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
```

Now I am getting new Error message

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe E:\pycharm\projecttelegram\MyPythonTesting_1.py 
ENTER THE MESSAGE:     test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 203, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 60, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 962, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request
    raise new_e
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1092, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 611, in connect
    self.sock = sock = self._new_conn()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 210, in _new_conn
    raise NameResolutionError(self.host, self, e) from e
urllib3.exceptions.NameResolutionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001EC5FA8BCD0>: Failed to resolve 'api.telegram.org' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot261600102:AAGxPuS8CVlJB_0tZYHCCeXV6VqD67uRljA/sendmessage?chat_id=MyPythonTesting&text=test (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001EC5FA8BCD0>: Failed to resolve 'api.telegram.org' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)"))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\pycharm\projecttelegram\MyPythonTesting_1.py", line 7, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot261600102:AAGxPuS8CVlJB_0tZYHCCeXV6VqD67uRljA/sendmessage?chat_id=MyPythonTesting&text=test (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001EC5FA8BCD0>: Failed to resolve 'api.telegram.org' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)"))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **don't use `core.telegram.org`**, if you want to use the Bot API use `api.telegram.org`.

Telegram provides [multiple api's](https://core.telegram.org/), you want to use the [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).

---

Looking further to the URL you're using:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_id}/sendmessage?chat_id={chat_id}&test={message}
```

Here you pass `test` with the `message`, if you look at the [`sendMessage` documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage), you'll see that `test` is not an accepted paramater, you need to use `text={message}`:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_id}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={message}
```

Comment: I corrected the mistake and i am getting the error below

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77284967/edit) button under your question to add details / error messages.

Comment: i am getting following error

Comment: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot261600102:AA*****CCeXV6VqD67uRljA/sendmessage?chat_id=MyPythonTesting&text=TEST (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002351417BCD0>: Failed to resolve 'api.telegram.org' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)"))